# Read/write speed HDD/SSD

Tags: hard-drive, video, ssd, encoding

I have some video files > 1 GB which I want to encode. My laptop has a SSD and a HDD. What would be better/faster for encoding?

1. Read the video files from the `SSD` and write the encoded files to the `SSD`
2. Read the video files from the `HDD` and write the encoded files to the `SSD`
3. Read the video files from the `SSD` and write the encoded files to the `HDD` (*I doubt that*)
4. Read the video files from the `HDD` and write the encoded files to the `HDD` (*I doubt that either*)

Comment: pure guess is it will make little difference, as it's mainly a CPU-intensive task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it will not matter.

Encoding is usually CPU bound. That means it will:

1. Read data slower than it can be provided by either SSD or HDD.
   As a result it does not matter which one you use.
2. Generate data slower and the write speed of either SSD or HDD
   As a result it does not matter which one you use.

Two possible exceptions:

1. Extremely slow disks and a fast CPU (e.g. a disk on an USB-1 enclosure).
2. Reading from the SSD might mean it can start a few ms earlier. Usually this is not an issue when running long (minutes+) encoding jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You have the order of speed roughly  correct - SSD to SSD will be the fastest by a significant margin and hdd to hdd slowest - but depending on the type of encoding the system may (or may not) be CPU bound, in which case focussing on disk won't have as much impact as focussing on CPU./encoding options.

It's possible that SSD to hdd could be faster then hdd to SSD or vice versa depending on how much compression the encoding does, and how fragmented the disk is.